# which characters should be passed in xml for invalid login

Tags: java, xml, selenium

**My Java**

```
package modules;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Config.Config;

public class Invalid_Login {
    String InvalidLogin_Status = null;
    String InvalidLogin_Message = null;

    @Test(dataProvider = "emplogin")
    @Parameters({"USERNAME", "PASSWORD"})
    public void Execute(String UserName, String Password) {
        Config.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log in")).click();
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys(UserName);
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys(Password);
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("wp-submit")).click();
        WebElement a = Config.driver.findElement(By.id("login_error"));
        System.out.println(a.getText());
        Assert.assertEquals("ERROR: Invalid username. Lost your password?", a.getText());
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "emplogin")
    public Object[][] logindata() {
        Object[][] credentials = new Object[5][2];
        //incorrect login/short login
        credentials[1][0] = "testss";
        credentials[1][1] = "testss";

        //empty login
        credentials[2][0] = "";
        credentials[2][1] = "empty login";

        // empty password
        credentials[3][0] = "emptypass";
        credentials[3][1] = "";

        // all empty
        credentials[4][0] = "";
        credentials[4][1] = "";

        //incorrect
        credentials[5][0] = "wrongusername";
        credentials[5][1] = "wrongpass";

        return credentials;
    }
}
```

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="DUMMY" parallel="tests" thread-count="1">
    <parameter name="RUNUSINGSG" value="N"/>
    <test name="Verify InvalidLogin Functionality By Passing Valid Username and password"/>

    <parameter name="BROWSERCODE" value="FF"/>
    <parameter name="URL" value="http://demo.rtcamp.com/rtmedia/"/>
    <parameter name="VERSION" value="ANY"/>
    <parameter name="PLATFORM" value="WINDOWS"/>
    <parameter name="TITLE" value="rtcamp - Empowering The Web With Wordpress!"/>
    <parameter name="USERNAME" value="swash"/>
    <parameter name="PASSWORD" value="123"/>

    <classes>
        <class name="modules.LaunchApplication"/>
        <class name="modules.Login"/>
    </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I want to test the login form for invalid data and I use dataprovider here  and i am going to  pass the data in xml file so I want know which values should  i use in xml file.for ex.  Should I use valid data or invalid data in value? Any help?.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot couple `@Parameters` and `@DataProvider` annotation on a `@Test` Method.

Parameters and DataProvider annotation were introduced into TestNG with the sole purpose of parameterizing tests.
They are provided as two options to parameterize your tests, but not meant to be used in conjunction with each other.

For what purpose are you passing this parameter username='swash' and password='123' to your test method seperately .I assume these are correct credentials otherwise you could have added this is your testng dataprovider itself

I would suggest you have two dataproviders one which supplies invalid login credentials like the above dataprovider (emplogin) and one with valid login credentials like one below ad pass this to method which checks successful login

**Note** : In your code you are using testng framework but you have imported wrong assertion package `import org.junit.Assert`; use `import org.testng.Assert`; instead

**EDIT**:

Example : For invalid login class

```
package modules;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Config.Config;

public class Invalid_Login {
    String InvalidLogin_Status = null;
    String InvalidLogin_Message = null;

    @Test(dataProvider = "emplogin")
    public void Execute(String UserName, String Password) {
        Config.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log in")).click();
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys(UserName);
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys(Password);
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("wp-submit")).click();
        WebElement a = Config.driver.findElement(By.id("login_error"));
        System.out.println(a.getText());
        Assert.assertEquals(a.getText(),"ERROR: Invalid username. Lost your password?");
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "emplogin")
    public Object[][] logindata() {
        Object[][] credentials = new Object[5][2];
        //incorrect login/short login
        //Array index should start with 0 as we have mentioned[5][2]
        //it should contain 5 rows and 2 columns
        credentials[0][0] = "testss";//credentials[1][0] = "testss";
        credentials[0][1] = "testss";//credentials[1][1] = "testss";

        //empty login
        credentials[1][0] = "";
        credentials[1][1] = "

        // empty password
        credentials[2][0] = "emptypass";
        credentials[2][1] = "";

        // all empty
        credentials[3][0] = "";//credentials[2][0] = "";
        credentials[3][1] = "";

        //incorrect
        credentials[4][0] = "wrongusername";
        credentials[4][1] = "wrongpass";

        return credentials;
    }
}
```

**Testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="DUMMY" parallel="tests" thread-count="1">
    <test name="Verify InvalidLogin Functionality By Passing Valid Username and password">
    <classes>
        <class name="modules.Invalid_Login"/>
    </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

You need not specify the invalid login parameters in xml file the dataprovider will supply the invalid credentials as an object array to test method (Execute).Try the above code for example

Hope this helps you...If i have wrongly understood your question or if you  have any queries. Kindly get back

Comment: actually i am first time using dataprovider for testing invalid login and i am going to run this test from an xml file,and xml file requires parameters and value so i want to know which parameters should i pass in my xml file.valid or invalid?hope u understand

Comment: @Ab123 Sorry for the late reply was busy with my work.I can't understand your problem the xml file does not require you to pass parameters and value you can do it using dataprovider itself...pls refer my edit

Comment: So there is no requirement of passing the parameters in xml file when we use dataproviders?

Comment: @Ab123 Yes..there is no need to pass parameters in xml file when we use dataproviders.Kindly get back if you face any problems

Comment: I got one more issue "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
" exception.

Comment: This error occurs when the index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.We have missed the zeroth index. pls refer the above edited code"For invalid login class".Hope it helps you

Comment: By changing the index[0][0] it is working fine for first credential and it is not executing from second credentials and getting the error org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Log in"} and I think it is checking for linktext(login) which is not available at login page(visible at homw page only) hence it is giving the error.so how to tackle with this error.

Comment: I can't understand your problem your checking with invalid credentials in method "Execute" which gets login_error text and asserts it.pls do not keep your homepage scripts in 'Execute' method place them separately in another test method.because data provider will call the method five times in the above case with different parameters as specified in the object array.